# Does a user's knowledge of operating system interactions carry over to a browser?

Tags: usability, navigation, design-patterns

My coworkers and I recently discussed an article criticizing the hamburger icon + drawer navigation approach, and began to debate whether Window's "Start" button utilizes the same approach.

There are plenty of existing debates on the pros, cons, etc. of the hamburger, so I do not think there is a reason to continue that here. However, I would love to hear your opinion on how the "Start" button compares to the hamburger icon.

- Aside from user familiarity due to frequency of use, do you see a clear difference between the "Start" button and the hamburger icon?
- Are labeling, visual design, and/or icon position the only possible factors here?
- Do users' knowledge of operating system interactions carry over to a browser?

On a side note, does anyone know if the "Start" button heavily criticized when it was first released?

Edit: I should clarify that the hamburger menu I am thinking of for this example is fairly large (say 50+ items) and contains no alert/notification style content, just navigational links to pages within the website?

Comment: It's funny that you have to click start to shutdown.

Comment: @MattRockwell Well, if you made the shutdown command too straightforward and available, users would do it on accident all the time, right?

Comment: "does anyone know if the "Start" button was heavily criticized when it was first released?" I'm not sure about this but as a counterpoint, remember the backlash when it was removed in Windows 8? I think that clearly indicated a "familiarity due to frequency of use"

Comment: @DasBeasto Definitely. That had to be a really tricky transition for the Windows team to plan a user on-boarding strategy around.

Comment: @DasBeasto Yes, in 1995 there was much amusement about the *Shut down* command being on the Windows 95 *Start* menu. I remember it being discussed at work by the IT department when the previews were released.

Comment: @DasBeasto I checked around. One colleague remembers much fuss and mirth about this design choice. Another colleague, who went to CHI  (annual human-factors conference) the year after Win95 was released, reports that the Microsoft team was asked about this. Apparently, they said On/Off go together so Start is the right place.

Comment: @JeromeR Interesting, I thought their reasoning would have been more along the lines of "Well you're starting the shutdown process so.." but I suppose that reasoning is just as _valid?_

Comment: @DasBeasto No, just as *invalid*. it was generally agreed that this was a poor design solution, not to be emulated in other products.

Answer (score 2):

While there are quite a few similarities between the Start menu used in Windows and a hamburger menu, I'd say there are a few key differences in their execution.

**Amount of Content**

One of the biggest arguments against hamburger menus is the amount of navigation friction they introduce. Usually these menus contain a small number of buttons or functions that could easily be fit elsewhere in the UX workflow. In the case of the Windows start menu it holds quite a bit more than an average hamburger menu; A full list of installed software, additional shortcuts, quick links to system functionality, and with the more modern versions of Windows, a search dialog. Clearly not something you want to present at all times to the user, as that would take up considerable real estate on the screen.

**Dynamic Content**

Another complaint I see against hamburger menus is their lack of "glanceability". If you place things like inbox notifications or alerts inside a menu that remains hidden most of the time, it's putting up an unnecessary barrier between the user and that data. The start menu does not really contain any of this dynamic data. (With the exception of Windows 10 live tiles, but that's more superfluous data than anything) If the user is navigating to the start menu, it's because they are looking to perform a specific action on a known set of data.

As to your question about negative feedback towards the start menu when it was first introduced; I can't remember anything really negative being said about it. Moving from Program Manager to the much easier to use Start Menu in Windows 95 was rather nice. Some related reading you might find interesting: http://www.sigchi.org/chi96/proceedings/desbrief/Sullivan/kds_txt.htm

I'm sure someone else can cover what I'm trying to say more eloquently, but I figured I'd give it a shot.

Comment: Thanks @JonBee. I agree with your points. What if the hamburger menu were fairly large (say 50+ items) and contained no alert/notification style content, just navigational links to pages within the website?

Comment: @Andy I think that that's around the point when a hamburger menu actually is useful. Despite how they get badly used at time, there is a reason they exist after all.

Answer (score 2):

One of the critical piece that made the Start button work was a [sustained, ubiquitous, multi-million dollar ad campaign](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=chTftktWmto). It would be hard to understate the effect of this on users' ability to understand the Start button.

Comment: Ahh, good point.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with the points stated by @JonBee, but I think the main difference lies in  the options (content) we are showing to the users, and the purpose of an App or a PC.

Usually, we give our mobile users content to consume as soon as they get into our app, so they don't have to wonder what to do... they just start consuming what's on the screen -plus, they always open your app for a specific purpose-.

On the other hand, if you present a clean Windows installation to a user, they do need a hint on what to do next, as there is no content to consume there. So a "Start" button might call your attention if you are staring at an empty screen -and with a possible different purpose each time-.

So, in front of these two situations, is no-brainer why users in mobile many times "forget" that the hamburger icon is there -content they are looking for is usually right there in the screen-; and why Windows users consistently need a hint on where to start a task they want to do -many purposes/different things to do-.

Windows Vs App example:

[image: Windows]
<sub>(source: [50webs.com](http://todaysgeek.50webs.com/Screenshots/1.jpg))</sub>
    [image: App]